# How does logstash route the data to a NEW primary ES node, not the old one?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, sharding, failover

I'm trying to wrap my head around something. I have 3 ES nodes, with just 1 shard for simplicity. The first node is just the master node. The second node holds the primary shard and the third one holds the replica shard.

Master Node: 10.42.0.100:9200

Data node1 (Primary): 10.42.0.101:9200

Data node2 (Replica): 10.42.0.102:9200

This is my config from logstash, where I write the data:

```
output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts  =>  ["10.42.0.101:9200"]
                index => "twitter"
                document_type => "tweet"
                template => "/etc/logstash/template/twitter_template.json"
                template_name => "twitter"
        }
}
```

Everything looks good and logstash will write the data to my primary ES node. However - what if that node completely dies? How do I make it failover and write to the replica node?

According the elastic.co documentation, the master node keeps track of all this and will assign a new primary node if something goes wrong. However, my logstash config doesn't know this since it's hardcoded to the first node. How can I notify logstash that the primary is down and a new one has been assigned?

First, I was thinking of this kind of configuration.

```
output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts  =>  ["10.42.0.101:9200", "10.42.0.102:9200"]
                index => "twitter"
                document_type => "tweet"
                template => "/etc/logstash/template/twitter_template.json"
                template_name => "twitter"
        }
}
```

Writing data to both the replica and primary - but this is just wrong right? The primary already replicates data to the second node so it doesn't make any sense to write to them both.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you explicitly defined your first node to be master only and the others to be data only, your cluster is not really set as you think.

By "luck", node1 is the master, node2 holds a primary shard and node3 holds a replica.

If you defined anything specific, like node1 master only, I'd recommend not doing so on a 3 nodes cluster and keep all the default values instead.

Anyway, coming back to your question, Logstash only route data to the nodes you specified, wherever the primary is. Logstash does not know anything about the physical location of the data. Elasticsearch coordinating node (the one which is receiving a request) is doing the routing to the right machines then.

So, I'd just recommend doing:

```
output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts  =>  ["10.42.0.100:9200", "10.42.0.101:9200", "10.42.0.102:9200"]
                index => "twitter"
                document_type => "tweet"
                template => "/etc/logstash/template/twitter_template.json"
                template_name => "twitter"
        }
}
```

And I'd recommend watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilP7tG6tabI).

Comment: Thank you for you answer. 
You specified all the nodes in the config, including the master only node. Shouldn't the data just be routed to the data nodes? Or should you specify all the nodes regardless of which one, and logstash figures out which one is the primary, replica, master etc?

And I don't have a coordinating node in my cluster. So if I understand you correctly, the data should be routed to coordinating nodes in order to be fault tolerant?

Comment: If it's a master only yes. But I don't recommend having one single master eligible node.

Comment: Each node that is getting a request is a coordinating node. So in that case all 3 nodes will be coordinating nodes